# Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel for connection using Client Certificate for some machines only

Tags: c#, ssl, certificate

I have some code that works on most machines, but fails on some.

In order to connect to a third-party API, my C# .Net 4.6.1 program needs to send a Client Certificate along with the request, as part of the verification. Most of the code involved in sending to and receiving from the API was generated from a WSDL they provided, I just had to implement it.

The implementation is in two halves, the first is to install the Certificate if it's missing, which is run on program startup.

```
private static void InstallCertificate(string certPath)
{
    if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(certPath) || !File.Exists(certPath))
    {
        return;
    }

    string certPass = "MyPassword";

    try
    {
        // Create a collection object and populate it using the PFX file
        X509Certificate2Collection collection = new X509Certificate2Collection();
        collection.Import(certPath, certPass, X509KeyStorageFlags.PersistKeySet | X509KeyStorageFlags.MachineKeySet);

        foreach(X509Certificate2 cert in collection)
        {
            try
            {
                var store = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.CurrentUser);
                store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadWrite);
                if(!store.Certificates.Contains(cert))
                {
                    store.Add(cert);
                }
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                // Log any errors
            }
        }
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        // Log any errors
    }

}
```

The second is to retrieve the Certificate as part of the request creation:-

```
private StoredValueClient CreateStoredValueClient()
{
    var binding = new BasicHttpBinding();
    binding.Security.Mode = BasicHttpSecurityMode.Transport;
    binding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.Certificate;
    binding.Security.Message.ClientCredentialType = BasicHttpMessageCredentialType.Certificate;

    var baseAddress = new Uri(StaticValues.APIBaseAddress);
    var endpointAddress = new EndpointAddress(baseAddress);

    var storedValueClient = new StoredValueClient(binding, endpointAddress);
    storedValueClient.ClientCredentials.ServiceCertificate.Authentication.TrustedStoreLocation = StoreLocation.CurrentUser;
    storedValueClient.ClientCredentials.ClientCertificate.SetCertificate(StoreLocation.CurrentUser, StoreName.My, X509FindType.FindBySerialNumber, StaticValues.APICertificateSerialNo);

    return storedValueClient;
}
```

"StoredValueClient" is part of the code created from the WSDL, and uses the "System.ServiceModel.ClientBase" model.

Two notes on the above:-

1. Because it uses the "System.ServiceModel.ClientBase" model, the only way to set a Certificate seems to be via "ClientCredentials.ClientCertificate.SetCertificate", which can only get a Certificate from the store.

I can't find any methods or overloads to get a Certificate from a file.

Nor can I find any methods or overloads that allow me to pass in the password for the Private key, which is an issue as that is required for the Certificate to work. However, that is solved by point 2.

2. Calling "InstallCertificate" on program startup does associate the password with the Certificate

Even if the Certificate is already there, simply opening the file containing it tells Windows that this is the password for the Certificate in the Store, and the system works.

Without doing this (for example, manually installing the Certificate once), Windows will only remember the password until the next reboot, at which point the system will stop working.

I hate this workaround, so if anyone knows how within "System.ServiceModel.ClientBase" to either bypass the  Store and load a certificate from a file, or how to pass the password as a parameter using "ClientCredentials.ClientCertificate.SetCertificate" I'd love to know, thanks!

However, that's not the main issue, the code does indeed work, on the majority of machines.

It works on every machine I have access to (about a dozen, using Windows 7, 10, and 11), plus my test VMs, and it works on a fellow Developer's machines, and the Tester's machines.

However, it does not work on one of the Project Manager's machines (it does on his other two), nor does it work on some live User machines. On those machines, it fails with:-

```
System.ServiceModel.Security.SecurityNegotiationException: Could not establish secure channel for SSL/TLS with authority 'thirdpartysite'. ---> System.Net.WebException: The request was aborted: Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel.

   at System.Net.HttpWebRequest.GetResponse()

   at System.ServiceModel.Channels.HttpChannelFactory`1.HttpRequestChannel.HttpChannelRequest.WaitForReply(TimeSpan timeout)
```

In order to track down the issue, I tested various hypotheses:-

1. I checked that TLS was enabled on the non-working machines

It was, and other connections to other APIs within the program also require TLS, and they work.

2. I tried connecting without using a Certificate at all

In this case I got a completely different error, so it's not that, it is getting a Certificate

3. I tried changing the APICertificateSerialNo so it couldn't find it

Again, I got a completely different error, so it's not that, it is finding the specific Certificate

4. I tried changing the APICertificateSerialNo to a different Certificate and sent that instead

This time, I got the same error, so it seems like there is an issue with the Certificate being sent, on some machines it's incorrect in some way?

5. I made the system display the Certificate details on the screen

And they were identical on both working and non-working machines, so both definitely have the Certificate in the Store, and both are retrieving it, it's just not working on some machines.

6. I tried running normally and as Administrator

In all cases, the software is installed and run under an Administrator account, and it made no difference if I simply ran it normally, or specifically ran it as Administrator.

So, I took a couple of working machines and a couple of non-working machines, ran a bunch of tests, pored over a lot of logs, and noticed the following:-

1. In order to retrieve the Certificate from the Store, Windows attempts to log the current User back in.

Not sure why, but apparently it does. Every time I attempt to retrieve the Certificate, I get a series of login entries in Windows Event Viewer, under the Security section.

2. On working machines, I get multiple "Success" entries.

It varied between machines, some gave more than others, anything from two per attempt to eight per attempt, although it was always consistent per machine.

[Success Log Entries](https://i.stack.imgur.com/G1Fcg.png)

```
An account was successfully logged on.

Subject:
    Security ID:        SYSTEM
    Account Name:       AccountName
    Account Domain:     AccountDomain
    Logon ID:       0x3E7

Logon Information:
    Logon Type:     5
    Restricted Admin Mode:  -
    Remote Credential Guard:    -
    Virtual Account:        No
    Elevated Token:     Yes

Impersonation Level:        Impersonation

New Logon:
    Security ID:        SYSTEM
    Account Name:       SYSTEM
    Account Domain:     NT AUTHORITY
    Logon ID:       0x3E7
    Linked Logon ID:        0x0
    Network Account Name:   -
    Network Account Domain: -
    Logon GUID:     {00000000-0000-0000-0000-000000000000}

Process Information:
    Process ID:     0x378
    Process Name:       C:\Windows\System32\services.exe

Network Information:
    Workstation Name:   -
    Source Network Address: -
    Source Port:        -

Detailed Authentication Information:
    Logon Process:      Advapi  
    Authentication Package: Negotiate
    Transited Services: -
    Package Name (NTLM only):   -
    Key Length:     0

This event is generated when a logon session is created. It is generated on the computer that was accessed.

The subject fields indicate the account on the local system which requested the logon. This is most commonly a service such as the Server service, or a local process such as Winlogon.exe or Services.exe.

The logon type field indicates the kind of logon that occurred. The most common types are 2 (interactive) and 3 (network).

The New Logon fields indicate the account for whom the new logon was created, i.e. the account that was logged on.

The network fields indicate where a remote logon request originated. Workstation name is not always available and may be left blank in some cases.

The impersonation level field indicates the extent to which a process in the logon session can impersonate.

The authentication information fields provide detailed information about this specific logon request.
    - Logon GUID is a unique identifier that can be used to correlate this event with a KDC event.
    - Transited services indicate which intermediate services have participated in this logon request.
    - Package name indicates which sub-protocol was used among the NTLM protocols.
    - Key length indicates the length of the generated session key. This will be 0 if no session key was requested.
    
    

Special privileges assigned to new logon.

Subject:
    Security ID:        SYSTEM
    Account Name:       SYSTEM
    Account Domain:     NT AUTHORITY
    Logon ID:       0x3E7

Privileges:     SeAssignPrimaryTokenPrivilege
            SeTcbPrivilege
            SeSecurityPrivilege
            SeTakeOwnershipPrivilege
            SeLoadDriverPrivilege
            SeBackupPrivilege
            SeRestorePrivilege
            SeDebugPrivilege
            SeAuditPrivilege
            SeSystemEnvironmentPrivilege
            SeImpersonatePrivilege
            SeDelegateSessionUserImpersonatePrivilege
            
            
            
Credential Manager credentials were read.

Subject:
    Security ID:        SYSTEM
    Account Name:       AccountName
    Account Domain:     AccountDomain
    Logon ID:       0x3E7
    Read Operation:     Enumerate Credentials

This event occurs when a user performs a read operation on stored credentials in Credential Manager.



Credential Manager credentials were read.

Subject:
    Security ID:        AccountDomain\Username
    Account Name:       AccountName
    Account Domain:     AccountDomain
    Logon ID:       0xF7640
    Read Operation:     Enumerate Credentials

This event occurs when a user performs a read operation on stored credentials in Credential Manager.
```

3. On non-working machines, I always get five login entries, four failures and one success.

[Failure Log Entries](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UblHn.png)

The Success appears to be where it retrieves the Certificate, because as noted above it does get it.

```
Cryptographic operation.

Subject:
    Security ID:        AccountDomain\AccountName
    Account Name:       AccountName
    Account Domain:     AccountDomain
    Logon ID:       0x8D54D24

Cryptographic Parameters:
    Provider Name:  Microsoft Software Key Storage Provider
    Algorithm Name: UNKNOWN
    Key Name:   {GUID}
    Key Type:   Machine key.

Cryptographic Operation:
    Operation:  Open Key.
    Return Code:    0x80090016
    
    
    
Key migration operation.  NOTE : THIS IS THE AUDIT SUCCESS ENTRY

Subject:
    Security ID:        AccountDomain\AccountName
    Account Name:       AccountName
    Account Domain:     AccountDomain
    Logon ID:       0x8D54D24

Process Information:
    Process ID:     14524
    Process Creation Time:  ‎2023‎-‎03‎-‎31T10:41:12.598323800Z

Cryptographic Parameters:
    Provider Name:  Microsoft Software Key Storage Provider
    Algorithm Name: RSA
    Key Name:   {GUID}
    Key Type:   Machine key.

Additional Information:
    Operation:  Import of persistent cryptographic key.
    Return Code:    0x0
    
    
    
Cryptographic operation.

Subject:
    Security ID:        AccountDomain\AccountName
    Account Name:       AccountName
    Account Domain:     AccountDomain
    Logon ID:       0x8D54D24

Cryptographic Parameters:
    Provider Name:  Microsoft Software Key Storage Provider
    Algorithm Name: RSA
    Key Name:   {GUID}
    Key Type:   Machine key.

Cryptographic Operation:
    Operation:  Create Key.
    Return Code:    0x80090010
    
    
    
Cryptographic operation.

Subject:
    Security ID:        AccountDomain\AccountName
    Account Name:       AccountName
    Account Domain:     AccountDomain\AccountName
    Logon ID:       0x8D54D24

Cryptographic Parameters:
    Provider Name:  Microsoft Software Key Storage Provider
    Algorithm Name: UNKNOWN
    Key Name:   {GUID}
    Key Type:   Machine key.

Cryptographic Operation:
    Operation:  Open Key.
    Return Code:    0x80090016
    
    
    
Cryptographic operation.

Subject:
    Security ID:        AccountDomain\AccountName
    Account Name:       AccountName
    Account Domain:     AccountDomain
    Logon ID:       0x8D54D24

Cryptographic Parameters:
    Provider Name:  Microsoft Software Key Storage Provider
    Algorithm Name: UNKNOWN
    Key Name:   {GUID}
    Key Type:   Machine key.

Cryptographic Operation:
    Operation:  Open Key.
    Return Code:    0x80090016
```

Error codes 0x80090016 and 0x80090010 returned in the “Audit Failure” messages seem to mostly relate to PIN issues logging in to Windows, or “keyset does not exist”.

None of the machines have a PIN set up.

Also, the Success messages mention "Credential Manager credentials were read.", which I hoped would be the issue, and the non-working machines would simply be missing entries in Credential Manager.

However, when I checked the working machines, some had no entries at all under Credential Manager, and adding in an entry on the non-working machines did not fix the issue.

So, currently my issue seems to be that Windows logs the current User in again in order to retrieve the Certificate, rather than simply retrieving it, and on some machines that login fails.

Because it does still return the Certificate with all its details, my assumption is that the login failures are preventing the Private Key from being returned, which my earlier tests showed is required for the Certificate to work.

Edit from comment: Charlieface

```
Sounds like Private Key permissions are wrong. 

See eg https://www.codyhosterman.com/2019/06/assigning-read-access-to-windows-private-key/
```

I had a look at that link, thanks. Their problem was the program not being run in Administrator mode, and so not having access by default. I get the problem in normal or Administrator mode, and it's being installed and run under an Administrator account specifically created for the software to run under.

I went to try explicitly setting the permissions anyway, because it's a good suggestion, but whilst their certificates were installed under the Local Computer account, mine are installed under the Current User account ( var store = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.CurrentUser); ), and there is no "Manage Private Keys" option on the menu, presumably because there is only one User who can see it.

[No Manage Private Keys Option](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zG2O3.png)

So hopeful you'd cracked it there, thanks for the suggestion!

Comment: Sounds like Private Key permissions are wrong. See eg https://www.codyhosterman.com/2019/06/assigning-read-access-to-windows-private-key/

Answer (score 0):

The solution from @Charlieface 's comment fixed it for me:

> Sounds like Private Key permissions are wrong. See eg https://www.codyhosterman.com/2019/06/assigning-read-access-to-windows-private-key/

Your user might not have permission to access the certificate.

Try adding read permissions for your user:

- Open *Manage computer certificates* from the start menu.
- Navigate to your certificate, e.g. *Personal* > *Certificates* > *MyCertificate*.
- Right-click, select *All Tasks* > *Manage Private Keys*.
- Add your User, give it **Read** permissions to the certificate.

This resolved my similar issue.
I could use the certificate as Admin, to connect remotely, but not as a regular user.

## Illustrated process

Open "Manage Computer Certificates" from the start menu.

Then open the permissions for the certificate:

[image: opening the permissions for the certificate]

Then add Read permissions for your user:

[image: adding permissions for the local user to access the certificate]