# System.ServiceModel.Security.X509CertificateInitiatorClientCredential.SetCertificate From File not Certificate Store

Tags: c#, x509certificate, pfx

In order to connect to a third-party API, my C# .Net 4.6.1 program needs to send a Client Certificate along with the request, as part of the verification. Most of the code involved in sending to and receiving from the API was generated from a WSDL they provided, I just had to implement it.

The code created from the WSDL creates a class "StoredValueClient", based on the  "System.ServiceModel.ClientBase" model, so the only way I can see to set the Certificate is using the "System.ServiceModel.Security.X509CertificateInitiatorClientCredential.SetCertificate" method, as shown below:-

```
private StoredValueClient CreateStoredValueClient()
{
    var binding = new BasicHttpBinding();
    binding.Security.Mode = BasicHttpSecurityMode.Transport;
    binding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.Certificate;
    binding.Security.Message.ClientCredentialType = BasicHttpMessageCredentialType.Certificate;

    var baseAddress = new Uri(StaticValues.APIBaseAddress);
    var endpointAddress = new EndpointAddress(baseAddress);

    var storedValueClient = new StoredValueClient(binding, endpointAddress);
    storedValueClient.ClientCredentials.ServiceCertificate.Authentication.TrustedStoreLocation = StoreLocation.CurrentUser;
    storedValueClient.ClientCredentials.ClientCertificate.SetCertificate(StoreLocation.CurrentUser, StoreName.My, X509FindType.FindBySerialNumber, StaticValues.APICertificateSerialNo);

    return storedValueClient;
}
```

There are two problems with this method:-

1. The Certificate needs to be in the Certificate Store for it to work
2. There is no overload that allows for passing through the Password for the Private Key

The second is a fairly big problem, as the Certificate doesn't work without the Private Key, and the Private Key can't be retrieved without the Password.

To get round both of these, I simply added the below code to the startup code of the program:-

```
private static void InstallCertificate(string certPath)
{
    if(string.IsNullOrEmpty(certPath) || !File.Exists(certPath))
    {
        return;
    }

    string certPass = "MyPassword";

    try
    {
        // Create a collection object and populate it using the PFX file
        X509Certificate2Collection collection = new X509Certificate2Collection();
        collection.Import(certPath, certPass, X509KeyStorageFlags.PersistKeySet | X509KeyStorageFlags.MachineKeySet);

        foreach(X509Certificate2 cert in collection)
        {
            try
            {
                var store = new X509Store(StoreName.My, StoreLocation.CurrentUser);
                store.Open(OpenFlags.ReadWrite);
                if(!store.Certificates.Contains(cert))
                {
                    store.Add(cert);
                }
            }
            catch(Exception ex)
            {
                // Log any errors
            }
        }
    }
    catch(Exception ex)
    {
        // Log any errors
    }

}
```

This opens the Certificate pfx file using the password, and then adds the Certificate(s) to the Store if they're not already there.

It also has the secondary effect of associating the Password with the Certificate in the Store, even if the Certificate was already there, and thus the first chunk of code using "System.ServiceModel.Security.X509CertificateInitiatorClientCredential.SetCertificate" retrieves the Private Key as well.

The above combination of code works on most machines, but as I noted in a related question I posted ( [Could not create SSL/TLS secure channel for connection using Client Certificate for some machines only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76034413/could-not-create-ssl-tls-secure-channel-for-connection-using-client-certificate) ) Windows goes about retrieving the Certificates from the Store in an odd way, re-logging-in the current User in order to do so, and on some machines that re-logging-in fails, and I don't get the Private Key back.

The other question focuses on solving the Windows logging in issue, but as an alternative I'd like to know if there's a way to change the first section of code to load the Certificate and Private Key directly from the pfx file, instead of from the Certificate Store, i.e.:-

```
private StoredValueClient CreateStoredValueClient()
{
    var binding = new BasicHttpBinding();
    binding.Security.Mode = BasicHttpSecurityMode.Transport;
    binding.Security.Transport.ClientCredentialType = HttpClientCredentialType.Certificate;
    binding.Security.Message.ClientCredentialType = BasicHttpMessageCredentialType.Certificate;

    var baseAddress = new Uri(StaticValues.APIBaseAddress);
    var endpointAddress = new EndpointAddress(baseAddress);

    var storedValueClient = new StoredValueClient(binding, endpointAddress);

    // Not This : 
    storedValueClient.ClientCredentials.ServiceCertificate.Authentication.TrustedStoreLocation = StoreLocation.CurrentUser;
    storedValueClient.ClientCredentials.ClientCertificate.SetCertificate(StoreLocation.CurrentUser, StoreName.My, X509FindType.FindBySerialNumber, StaticValues.APICertificateSerialNo);

    // Something like this instead :
    storedValueClient.ClientCredentials.ClientCertificate.LoadCertificateFromFile(certPath, certPass);

    return storedValueClient;
}
```

Notes:-

StoredValueClient is an implementation of **System.ServiceModel.ClientBase**

storedValueClient.ClientCredentials.ClientCertificate is **System.ServiceModel.Security.X509CertificateInitiatorClientCredential**

Everything generated from the WSDL is based around the StoredValueClient class, so I'm stuck using that, I can't use a different system.

Comment: Sending the certificate between client and host is equivalent to giving a burglar the key to your house.  You never send the certificate along with the data.  You are probably using HTTPS which uses a certificate for encryption.  The certificate is never transmitted.  The server sends a certificate block with the names of the certificate.  The client either looks up the NAME in the stores or specify a particular certificate that will be used.  The server has certificates preloaded and only sends the names of the preloaded certificate names.